# Using paths with a spaces in batch script

Tags: windows, batch

How do I make something like this work?

```
SET DIR=c:\program files (x86)\dir\
%DIR%callee.exe
```

Normal solution, which is to use double quotes around the value of `DIR` variable works, but results in `"c:\program files (x86)\dir\"callee.exe` being called which just feels wrong.

Comment: You can use `"%DIR%callee.exe"` which expands to `"c:\program files (x86)\dir\callee.exe"`

Comment: Also you should probably use `set dir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\dir` (no trailing `\ `. Then you can use `%dir%\callee.exe` which looks more normal ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using paths with a spaces in batch script

You can make use of some other predefined environment variables:

```
F:\test>set
...
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
...
```

Use the following command (which looks "more normal"):

```
set dir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\dir
%dir%\callee.exe
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.